# python discord api: member.discriminator after the username layout change is hard to work with

Tags: python, discord

`member.discriminator` is used to access the four digits after a discord username. After the username requirements change, most users don't have discriminators anymore.

Before the username requirements change, we could join the username and discriminator together to generate unique id for a user, for example, `john0001` would be different from `john0002`.

If `john0001` changed to the new username format and chose `john0002` as their username, discord would allow it. But how to distinguish the users?

I don't know how to keep track of users now, since there are two different username formats.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Discord user has a unique ID to distinguish users from each other.
You can read more about it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.id).